# Get correct data on the odd no of records in datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a datalist in which have a label that shows the datetime and have a grid inside the datalist .The problem is that i get the desire format of time (for e.g 1:48 AM) and data inside the grid only on odd no of record for example 1 3 5 7 records are correct and 2 4 6 7 show the empty record in the grid and the label also show the incorrect format(10/21/2015 1:48:20 AM). Here is the code. onitemDataBound event

```
protected void dataListOrder_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Item.ItemType==ListItemType.Item)
            {

                Label date = e.Item.FindControl("lblOrderDate") as Label;
                string[] datesplit = date.Text.Split(' ');
                string time =string.Concat(datesplit[1]+" "+datesplit[2]);
                date.Text = time.ToString();

                int order_ID = Convert.ToInt32((e.Item.FindControl("orderid") as HiddenField).Value);
                GridView innerDataList = e.Item.FindControl("datalistOrderDetails") as GridView;
                string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConnection"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
                {
                    DataTable orderDetailDT = new DataTable();
                    con.Open();
                    string orderDetail = "select ItemName,Quantity from Order_Details where Order_ID=" + order_ID + "";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(orderDetail, con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    SqlDataAdapter orderDetailDA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    orderDetailDA.Fill(orderDetailDT);
                    innerDataList.DataSource = orderDetailDT;
                    innerDataList.DataBind();

                }




            }
        }
```

NOTE: I also try to use string format in aspx file to achieve my desired time format but it didn't work

```
<asp:Label ID="lblOrderDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("OrderDate","{0:t}") %>'.
```

Please guide me where the problem in the code why its only show data in odd no. Thankyou

Comment: For the time format specified in ASPX that "didn't work", you mean that it works only on odd line numbers, right? Have you tried removing the inner grid (and the code-behind that fills it) to isolate the OrderDate format problem? Solving that problem first may give you an idea about what is going wrong.

Comment: Yes time format is not working because i stored that datetime in this string format "DateTIme.Now.toString("g")" (i.e 10/21/2015 1:48 AM ) i think thats why {0:t} is not working. Therefore i change the time format on onitemdatabound but its only works on odd no and nested grid is also fill only on odd data..

Comment: @ConnorsFan I remove the inner grid and then try but still i get the time on the odd no. 
is this line is correct  if(e.Item.ItemType==ListItemType.Item). when i debug it show all the record but changes apply on the odd no. Please help

Comment: I added an official answer to your last question. Your last remark suggested that answer. If it solves your problem, I can say that you almost did it by yourself. :-)

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help. :) its working now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to change you condition from

```
if (e.Item.ItemType==ListItemType.Item)
```

to

```
if (e.Item.ItemType==ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType==ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
```